# Elementor: How to stop wordpress gallery at the end, no loop?

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress, gallery, elementor

I want my gallery to be stop at the end of the last pic from the gallery. Do, i have to add any jQuery for it? I have added this gallery from elementor widgets. please help

Added info:
after clicking the image a popup window open and we can use arrow to go left or right. I want when we reach the end of right image or left image the arrow will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

```
I assume, you have used gallery image carousel widget from elementor and want to disable loop, Please follow below steps.
1] Click on that element.
2] Go to the additional options tab.
3] Select No from infinite loop select box.
Please check attached screenshot, Which helps you. Please let us know if you want something else with the screenshot.
```

[image: enable/disable loop]

Comment: No, after clicking the image a popup window open and we can use arrow to go left or right. I want when we reach the end of right image or left image the arrow will stop working.